# simple question about UITextField and not working secureTextEntry

Tags: iphone

I have a password field with text "Password" and when user clicks, it gets cleared. Moreover I want to set the type of this textfield as secure but this doesn´t work.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

  if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@"Password"] || [textField.text isEqualToString:@"Email"])
  {
  textField.text = @"";
      textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the property in interface builder or when you initialize textfield remove the line from

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
}
```

I think you should set placeholder text as email or password and pre select the secure text entry from interface builder.That's it...

Comment: thanks I solved it. Anyway I still don´t understand why this line: textField.secureTextEntry = YES doesn´t work. When I change from already secured textfield (in IB) to unsecure : textField.secureTextEntry = NO, then in this way it works :|

Answer (score 6):

I've just had the same problem. I was changing the property from within the `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` call.

Moving the property change to the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` call fixed the problem. I believe the trick is to change it while the text field isn't the `becomeFirstResponder`.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if ([textField isEqual:_passwordField]) {
        textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply put your text in a placeholder and make your password textfield secure. Your problem will be solved :).

Comment: hmmn its simple way to accomplish it :)

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

  if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@"Password"] || [textField.text isEqualToString:@"Email"])
  {
  textField.text = @"";
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
  }
}
```

it can solve your problem , but it has a big bug. the shit UITextField .

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a little old, but in iOS 6 the UITextField "text" is now by default "Attributed" in Interface Builder. Switching this to be "Plain", which is how it was in iOS 5, fixes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your keyboard is present, `secureTextEntry` won't work. Because the `UITextInputTraits` Protocol doesn't change the `textfield` if the keyboard shows.
You can dismiss the keyboard, and it will work

```
[myTextField resignFirstResponder]
```